# Forecast the revenue for next month using 1 year historical data

Tags: python, excel, data-analysis

I am new in this field. So i want to ask how to forecast this data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCl1v.png)

to know how much revenue gain for next month for each views or watch time based on this data. thanks in advance

I'm trying to do regression but i don't know how to use it to see how much revenue each views or watch times. note that i got negative coefficient.

Comment: Have you considered the forecast() function?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.